# Cannot fetch the recent added data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a data through an *insert page* where data will be inserted using ***mysql***.
When I try to fetch the new inserted data, it won't fetch the data.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO bag(bid,bookno,name) VALUES ('','$bn','$n');
```

My data supposedly:

```
           bid   bookno     name
            1      23      mystery
            2      56      mystery
            3      89      mysteryy
```

When I fetch the *name* column, it fetches the *name="mystery"* smoothly, but it cannot fetch the *name ="mysteryy"* data which is just recently inserted to my database.

My fetch query is...

```
SELECT * FROM bag WHERE name='$name';
```

Where `$name=$_POST['nam'];`

This is my **HTML** code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookno[]" id="bookno" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="nam[]" id="nam" /></td>
```

The **PHP** insert code:

```
foreach($_POST['nam'] as $row=>$pro)
{
    if($pro!="")
    {
    $n=$pro;
    $bn=$_POST['bookno'][$row];
    }
}

$s=INSERT INTO bag(bid,bookno,name) VALUES ('','$bn','$n');
```

Comment: Have you tried using LIKE on your SELECT Query?

Comment: `select * from bag LIKE 'mystery%'` or `'$name%'`

Comment: if the data is mysttery how can i do this

Comment: Use `select * from bag LIKE 'myst%'` @TK91

Comment: Use `select * from bag LIKE '$name%'` @TK91 too many ways to do this. That is a start. Google "mysql like" for more information.

Comment: ok i will see in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ***LIKE*** in your ***SELECT*** statement. (and converting your code into ***MySQLi***):

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($yourConnection,$_POST['nam']); /* PRACTICE USING MYSQLI REAL ESCAPE STRING SO YOU CAN PREVENT SOME OF THE SQL INJECTION */

$result=($yourConnection,"SELECT * FROM bag WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'");
```

About the `$yourConnection` variable:

```
$yourConnection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","Username","Password","YourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `bid` column is set to auto increment, you'll want to set that field to `null` or just omit it. If that's your primary index and you pass it an empty string every time,it will only save the first one.

```
insert into bag(bid,bookno,name) values (null,'$bn','$n');
```

or simply

```
insert into bag(bookno,name) values ('$bn','$n');
```

Comment: bid is primary key and also auto increment

Comment: @TK91 check your database then, i bet you only have one row in there. fix your query and the rest will go in.

Comment: do not understand your answer